# Equivalent success rate

Tags: binomial-distribution, scipy

I'm training models whose objective is to guess the correct image out of $n_i$ images.
Let's say that in settings where $n_i = 2$ the model manages to guess correctly 90% of the time.
In settings with $n_i = 4$ the model scores much lower, which is not surprising, since the chance level for $n_i = 4$ is lower ($p = 0.25$) than in the former setting ($p = 0.5$).

In order to be able to compare the performances in these two settings, I need to find what success rate is "equivalent" to those 90% under $n = 4$.

**Is there a name for what I'm trying to achieve?
Is there a convenient function in scipy or similar package?**

My idea was to:

- convert the success rates to error rates ($q = 1 - p$) to minimize floating point errors,
- calculate the probability mass $x$ on a binomial distribution of $n_i = 2$,
- calculate the percent point function at point $x$ on a binomial distribution of $n_i = 4$,

My python/scipy code for the above is

```py
def equivalent_error_rate(q1, err, q2, n=500):
    cdf = st.binom.cdf(err * n, n, q1)
    return st.binom.ppf(cdf, n, q2) / n
```

The problem is that this approach is very prone to floating point errors and in the scenario above I get the same result for error rates $< 0.001$.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** To get started.

You don't say the number of images you use to assess a subject; whether your criterion for success is to do better than by chance alone $(1/2$ for 2 choices, $1/4$ for 4 choices); or whether you are testing a null hypothesis at the 5% level of significance.

So it's difficult to know how you want to make the 2-choice and 4-choice scenarios equivalent.

Here is *one attempt* to do that. Let the number of trials be 50 and take rejection of the null hypothesis of no better than average at the 5% level as evidence the subject is doing well. If that's a reasonable interpretation of you question and my assumptions make sense, then what I show below may be helpful.
If not, please edit your question to be more specific about the number of pictures to be identified (trials) and your criterion for a successful performance. Then one of us can try again.

**Two-choice scenario.** You can say that the subject is doing better than by guessing by testing $H_0: p \le 1/2$ against $H_a: p > 1/2.$ In that case, a test of $H_0$ is rejected at around
the 5% level of significance if the subject gets 31 or more right out of 50.

Under $H_0,$ the number $X$ guessed correct out of $n = 50$ has
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=50,p=1/2).$ And
$$P(X \ge 31\, |\,H_0) = 1 - P(X \le 30\, |\, H_0) = 0.059.$$ If you insist on
a significance level below 5%, then insist on $X \ge 32$ in order to reject $H_0.$
[Binomial distributions are discrete, so you can't usually get 5% exactly.
In R statistical software `pbinom` denotes a Binomial CDF; `qnorma` is the inverse CDF (quantile function).]

```
qbinom(.95, 50, .5)
[1] 31
1- pbinom(30, 50, .5)
[1] 0.05946023
1- pbinom(31, 50, .5)
[1] 0.03245432
```

[image]

R code for figure above:

```
x = 0:50;  PDF = dbinom(x, 50, .5)
plot(x, PDF, type="h", col="blue", main="BINOM(50,.5)")
 abline(v=30.5, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
```

**Four-choice scenario.**
You can say that the subject is doing better than by guessing by testing $H_0: p \le 1/4$ against $H_a: p > 1/4.$ In that case, a test at around
the 5% level of significance rejects $H_0$ if the subject gets 18 or more right out of 50.

Under $H_0,$ the number $X$ guessed correct out of $n = 50$ has
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=50,p=1/4).$ And
$$P(X \ge 18\, |\,H_0) = 1 - P(X \le 17\, |\, H_0) = 0.055.$$ If you insist on
a significance level below 5%, then insist on $X \ge 19$ in order to reject $H_0.

```
qbinom(.95, 50, .25)
[1] 18
1 - pbinom(17, 50, .25)
[1] 0.05512336
1 - pbinom(18, 50, .25)
[1] 0.02873316
```

[image]